# What is difference between define function by prototype and class property?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Follow my code,
Apple is define function by prototype.
Banana is define function by class property.

```
var Apple = function(){}
Apple.prototype.say = function(){
    console.debug('HelloWorld');
}
var Banana = function(){
    this.say = function(){
        console.debug('HelloWorld');
    }
}

var a = new Apple();
var b = new Banana();

a.say();
b.say();
```

Are these difference ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When you create more than one instance of Apple, you will still only have only one instance of `say()` in memory. However, when you create more than one instance of Banana, you will end up creating lots of instances of the `say()` function.

That's why prototypes save memory. You also avoid the processing cost of creating and assigning the `say()` function.

Also, if you change the parent object's properties, if the child does not replace that property, changes are visible from the child.

Comment: Also, changes to the prototype are "seen" by all instances, which may be useful in some cases.

Comment: Yes, it's sort of equivalent to a static in that sense.

Comment: I also wondered about inheritance so I made a fiddle. Result: it works both ways.  https://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/tfn71a96/

Answer (score 2):

prototype members are like class membeprototype members are like class member, while when u define it other way its not a class member. So if you are creating lot of object of Apple all will be sharing same function, while in case of banana, every object will have their own copy of function.
 Think prototype in javascript as static in C#.