# What is the difference between Something.prototype.else and Something.else

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

I am trying to understand object in JavaScript. Now I see a lot of different uses of object, and I can not tell them apart.

For starters, the biggest thing I want to know is what the difference is between these two

```
Something.prototype.else = function(){
  return 6;
}
```

And

```
Something.else = function(){
  return 6;
}
```

Both look different, but they are used in the same way, or am I mistaken.

Comment: there should be a zillion sites explaining the difference, have a go with google, read some bits ( maybe you'll learn more than just this piece of info )

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5912497/69820

Comment: Yes sorry for asking this. I will have a better look next time.

Comment: @PoelincaDorin Simply suggesting to search [isn't helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions). If you know of a resource related to the question, please share it.

Comment: @SaifBechan Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i understand how we should deal with the problem now, however what should i do in these kind of situations where the answer is realy simple and there are tons of resources explaining it flag it whont help and close it whont help either . I understand that a question needs and answer so that google searches will lead here but there are allready google searches that deal with this exact question way better than the answers found here so in the end we're populating google searches with poor answers, p.s. we need to move this conversation to meta

Comment: I flagged this for moderation attention. hope it gets deleted soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are familiar with other programming languages you can consider the second one to be a static method.

The first one you need an instance of the object in order to use it:

```
var x = new Something();
x.else();
```

The second one you do not need an instance in order to use it:

```
Something.else();
```

Comment: Another good interview question is "What is the difference between Something, Something() and new Something()"

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question for an interview for a JavaScript job indeed.

The difference is that `Something.else` overrides `Something.prototype.else`. That is, if you have both, `Something.else` will be used.

The advantage of having prototypes is that a prototype can be shared between many objects to reduce memory usage, make monkey-patching easier and implement prototype-based inheritance.