# JavaScript Garbage Collection on nested objects (DSL Development)

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, dsl

I want to create a DSL-like builder for my javascript object, but i'm not sure that DSL-Builder object is removed by garbage collector (created object). Here's the code:

```
function Section() {...}

Section.DSL = function() {
  var section = new Section();

  return {
    title: function(s) { section.title = s; },         /* Just for example */
    content: function(s) { section.content = s; },     /* Logic has been removed */
    section: section
  }
}

function section(builderFn) {
  var dsl = new Section.DSL();
  fn.call(dsl, dsl);

  return dsl.section;
}

/* Somewhere in the code */
var mySection = section(function(s) { 
  s.title('Hello, my section');
  s.content('We can put it in later');
});

/* I want my DSL object created internally by section method 
   to be removed by garbage collector */
```

I'm going to use DSL only to initialize a new instance of Section and fill its values using convenient methods. I want my DSL object to be disposed and i'm not sure that it is going to be according to my further usage of one of its members.

Maybe i should create a "dispose" method, which will set dsl.section to null or delete it using "delete dsl.section"? After that my section will be disconnected from DSL and it will be successfully removed by garbage collector and i continue to use it via new reference "mySection".

There is another idea:

There is a possibility to use DSL as singleton. It that case i have to
create a new Section object inside a "section" method and just assign
it to DSL object (which will be a singleton) before calling a builder
function. Is it a good solution? Example follows:

```
Section.DSL = {
  construct: function(section) {
    this.section = section;
    return this;
  }

  /* Builder methods */
}

function section(builderFn) {
  var section = new Section();

  /*  Imagine that DSL is just an object with a few functions 
      and construct just set its section variable and returns this
   */
  var dsl = Section.DSL(section); **/
  fn.call(dsl, dsl);

  return section;
}
```

Comment: If the GC will "deallocate" the memory when assigning null to a variable, it will usually also "deallocate" the memory when leaving it alone - of course a naive implementation might leave some "never to be used" variables as reachability roots. However, in this case it *won't do anything* because the object named by `section` is bound in a closure, and even a naive implementation generally can't screw that up because the object *is* reachable and thus cannot be "deallocated".

Comment: There is a possibility to use DSL as singleton. It that case i have to create a new Section object inside a "section" method and just assign it to DSL object (which will be a singleton) before calling a builder function. Is it a good solution?

Comment: "What?" I'd have to see that in code to be able to answer :) But keep in mind that GC is based on *object reachability*; the only issue is then what a [particular] JavaScript implementation determines to be a *root* of the reachability graph (in particular, with closures and variables that *could* be determined to never be accessed); and, if it even applies to the particular case at hand (it does not here). Cyclic references are guaranteed to be handled correctly in JS, but the timing/pressure of the GC is not.

Comment: @pst I've updated my question with another sample. I'm going to use that code with Node.

Comment: But in that case i'll have only one instance of DSL object in memory.

Comment: There might be less (function) objects, but the rules about object reachability are the same. Generally, for *many* objects, using the [[prototype]] (of which the new code is a "poor man's version" of) instead of "singleton/closure" methods can reduce memory usage. If so, and how much, depends upon the implementation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912497/what-is-difference-between-define-function-by-prototype-and-class-property and related questions for the basic difference(s).

Answer (score 0):

The GC is *only* concerned about [object-reachability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object). In any case, consider these examples:

```
function f (s) {
  // The variable "s" is a reachability root for the given scope;
  // any object that it names is guaranteed to be reachable
  // as long as the closure(s) below are reachable.
  return {
     getIt: function () { return s }
     setIt: function (_s) { s = _s }
  }
}
```

Example Case 1.

```
g = f({my: "Object"})
// Closures are no longer strongly reachable, and thus the object
// can be reclaimed.
// (Also note there are no other strong references to the object!)
g = null
// Told yah, so, oops exception!
g.getIt()
```

Example Case 2.

```
g = f({my: "Object"})
// The variable "s" bound by the closures has been re-assigned and
// thus no longer strongly references the original object;
// the original object is thus eligible for reclamation.
// (Note no other strong references!)
g.setIt(null)
// But of course we just have null now .. oops!
g.getIt().my
```

Example Case 3.

```
o = {my: "Object"}
g = f(o)
g.setIt(null)
// ..but the object is NOT eligible for reclamation because it is
// strongly reachable through "o" (which is a reachability root
// in this scope).
alert(o)
```

---

Now, the only real cases of interest (that I eluded to in my comments) is:

```
function f2(s) {
   var hash_of_s = hash(s)
   // The variable "s" is not accessed from any closure
   return {
      getHash: function () { return hash_of_s }
   }
}
g = f2(/* some LARGE object currently only reachable here */)
// Is the object referenced by "s" reclaimable here?
alert(g.getHash())
```

In this case, assuming the closure is strongly reachable, does "s" maintain reachability of the initial object?

An *implementation* could technically decide that "s" does not maintain reachability - but I do know how Node.js handles it.

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to use singleton DSL instance and assign a different object instances to it during the build process. It would be interesting to know how to analyze how Node.js GC will handle my situation with new instances inside closure.

Comment: @user2022814 Since your case is *not* the last scenario described (note that the parameter / original object is never used from within the closures), it doesn't really matter.